# Value of object don't change after post resquest

Tags: angular, http-post, subscription

There was not the first time that it happens. I call a post resquest by http:

```
this.http.post('url', this.simpleFilter)
  .map((response: Response) => response.json())
  .subscribe(data => {
    if (data.data) {
      this.simpleFilter = data.data;
      console.log(this.simpleFilter.type);
      console.log(this.simpleFilter);
      this.emissorFilter.next(this.simpleFilter);
    } else {
        swal(data.error, data.message, 'error');
    }

  },
  error => swal(data.error, data.message, 'error'));
```

Where I console.log(this.simpleFilter.type) print the type is

> 1

But when console.log(this.simpleFilter); print the object the type of object is

> 0

The another time that it happens the

P.S. The type object is a **enum**.

Why it is happening?

Answer (score 0):

It would really improve you question if you also posted the expected output and explained everything in more details but I'm pretty sure I understand what your problem is.

It happens because when you log a property which is a primitive (a number or a string) you take the value that exists right now and output it. When you print an object, you have a link which is displayed in the developer's tools. So the properties of the object in the console are updated when the data changes. That causes the difference. You can try to wrap both `console.log` statements in a `setTimeout` with a delay to see it the output is different.

Comment: Ok, I'll tried, but how can you see, when I use **this.ememberFilter.next(this.simpleFilter)** the object that I receive on subscription every have the type 0, intependly of the received type.

Comment: Well, I tried do it but, don't solve my problem. When log on console or I receive on subscription of **emissorFilter**, the type remains **0**.

Answer (score 0):

To set my object correctly on subscription, I have to wrap it in another obect. 
For example:

```
// in Service
let wrappedFilter = {
  type: this.simpleFilter.type,
  filter: this.simpleFilter
}
this.emissorWrappedFilter.next(wrappedFilter);
```

And in the subscription I replayed the object:

```
// in Component
this.service.emissorWrappedFilter.subscription ( wf => {
  this.simpleFilter = wf.filter;
  this.simpleFilter.type = wf.type;
  (...)
});
```

I do not know if it's the best way, but it works!